# Proxy to Redirect Traffic to Frontend and Backend

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, virtualhost

currently running an httpd site on centos 7, root folder is /var/www/anything.com/frontend/dist for frontend and /var/www/anything.com/backend/web for backend,I want to redirect all the anyting.com requests i.e. to frontend and site is displayed to visitors and something like anything.com/api to call backend, any suggestion to implement it, proxypass or redirect or rewrite anything with solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right, you want:

```
www.exemple.com/    --> /var/www/anything.com/frontend/dist
www.exemple.com/api --> /var/www/anything.com/backend/web
```

No need for redirections, or proxies.  Just define it directly in your configuration.

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *.80>
    ServerName www.exemple.com

    ErrorLog "logs/80_error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/80_access_log" combined

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/anything.com/frontend/dist"
    DirectoryIndex index.html

    Alias "/api" "/var/www/anything.com/backend/web"

</VirtualHost>
```

Make sure you have `LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so` uncommented since the alias module is required for the Alias directive.

---

A minimalist complete configuration could look like this (provided as-is, you will have to adjust certain values for your setup).

```
# Minimalist configuration
ServerRoot "DIRECTORY-WHERE-APACHE-IS-INSTALLED"

Listen 80

# Modules #################################################
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
#LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
#LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
#LoadModule authn_dbd_module modules/mod_authn_dbd.so
#LoadModule authn_socache_module modules/mod_authn_socache.so
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
#LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
#LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
#LoadModule authz_dbd_module modules/mod_authz_dbd.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
#LoadModule auth_form_module modules/mod_auth_form.so
#LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
#LoadModule allowmethods_module modules/mod_allowmethods.so
#LoadModule file_cache_module modules/mod_file_cache.so
#LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
#LoadModule cache_disk_module modules/mod_cache_disk.so
#LoadModule cache_socache_module modules/mod_cache_socache.so
#LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
#LoadModule socache_dbm_module modules/mod_socache_dbm.so
#LoadModule socache_memcache_module modules/mod_socache_memcache.so
#LoadModule watchdog_module modules/mod_watchdog.so
#LoadModule macro_module modules/mod_macro.so
#LoadModule dbd_module modules/mod_dbd.so
#LoadModule dumpio_module modules/mod_dumpio.so
#LoadModule buffer_module modules/mod_buffer.so
#LoadModule ratelimit_module modules/mod_ratelimit.so
LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
#LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
#LoadModule request_module modules/mod_request.so
#LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
#LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
#LoadModule sed_module modules/mod_sed.so
#LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
#LoadModule log_debug_module modules/mod_log_debug.so
#LoadModule log_forensic_module modules/mod_log_forensic.so
#LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
#LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
#LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
#LoadModule remoteip_module modules/mod_remoteip.so
#LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
#LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
#LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
#LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
#LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so
#LoadModule proxy_scgi_module modules/mod_proxy_scgi.so
#LoadModule proxy_uwsgi_module modules/mod_proxy_uwsgi.so
#LoadModule proxy_fdpass_module modules/mod_proxy_fdpass.so
#LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so
#LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
#LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
#LoadModule proxy_express_module modules/mod_proxy_express.so
#LoadModule proxy_hcheck_module modules/mod_proxy_hcheck.so
#LoadModule session_module modules/mod_session.so
#LoadModule session_cookie_module modules/mod_session_cookie.so
#LoadModule session_dbd_module modules/mod_session_dbd.so
LoadModule slotmem_shm_module modules/mod_slotmem_shm.so
#LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
#LoadModule lbmethod_byrequests_module modules/mod_lbmethod_byrequests.so
#LoadModule lbmethod_bytraffic_module modules/mod_lbmethod_bytraffic.so
#LoadModule lbmethod_bybusyness_module modules/mod_lbmethod_bybusyness.so
#LoadModule lbmethod_heartbeat_module modules/mod_lbmethod_heartbeat.so
LoadModule unixd_module modules/mod_unixd.so
#LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
#LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
#LoadModule cgid_module modules/mod_cgid.so
#LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
#LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
#LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
#LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
#LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
#LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so

<IfModule unixd_module>
    User YOUR-APACHE-USER
    Group YOUR-APACHE-GROUP
</IfModule>

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

# Logs ####################################################
ErrorLog "logs/error_log"
LogLevel warn
<IfModule log_config_module>
    #
    # The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
    # a CustomLog directive (see below).
    #
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    #
    # The location and format of the access logfile (Common Logfile Format).
    # If you do not define any access logfiles within a <VirtualHost>
    # container, they will be logged here.  Contrariwise, if you *do*
    # define per-<VirtualHost> access logfiles, transactions will be
    # logged therein and *not* in this file.
    #
    #CustomLog "logs/access_log" common

    #
    # If you prefer a logfile with access, agent, and referer information
    # (Combined Logfile Format) you can use the following directive.
    #
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>

# Mime ####################################################
<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types

    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
</IfModule>

# Default configurations ##################################
Timeout 60
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
UseCanonicalName Off
ServerTokens Prod
ServerSignature Off
HostnameLookups Off

# MPM configurations ######################################
PidFile "logs/httpd.pid"
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers             3
    MinSpareThreads         75
    MaxSpareThreads        250
    ThreadsPerChild         25
    MaxRequestWorkers      400
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
MaxMemFree 2048

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

# VirtualHost #############################################
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName YOUR-SERVER
    ServerAdmin YOUR-EMAIL

    LogLevel debug
    ErrorLog "logs/80_error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/80_access_log" combined

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/anything.com/frontend/dist"
    <Directory "/var/www/anything.com/frontend/dist">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <IfModule dir_module>
        DirectoryIndex index.html
    </IfModule>

    Alias "/api" "/var/www/anything.com/backend/web"
    <Directory "/var/www/anything.com/backend/web">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I tried but couldn't succeed, could you please elaborate it more for me with complete test VH?